# Not able to clear hibernate cache

Tags: java, hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

I am using broadleaf demo application which has hibernate configured with ECache. I also have a external application which is interacting with same db directly.
When I update db using external application, my broadleaf application  unware of those changes throws duplicate primary key while creating new entities. I am trying to resolve this issue by clearing out the hibernate cache periodically which enables hibernate to build the cache from scratch and hence everything syncs up.
I am using following code to clear out the second level cache.

```
Cache cache = sessionFactory.getCache();
String entityName = "someName";
cache.evictEntityRegion(entityName);
```

But, this doesn't seem to work.

I even tried to clear the cahche manually using JMX listeners like **visualvm**. But this also doesn't work. I am still getting old primary key values in my API's. Is this because only second level cache is being cleared leaving first level cache? I am stuck here. Can any one please help with this issue?

**UPDATED :**
Let's say I have application **A** and **B**. A uses broadleaf and B uses raw SQL queries to insert into db. I create few orders using application A and then I insert few orders directly in db using application B along with I update the SEQUENCE_GENERATOR table with max(order_id) + 1. Afterward when I try to create order using application A, it throws duplicate primary key exception. I tried to debug into the issue where I found that **IdOverrideTableGenerator** is still giving my old primary key. This made me curious about the second level cache. Doesn't broadleaf uses **SEQUENCE_GENERATOR** for starting references for primary key generation and maintains current state in cache ? In my case even updating the  SEQUENCE_GENERATOR doesn't ensure the fresh and unique primary key.

Comment: The max(order_id) approach won't work. The default increment size is 50 for OrderImpl. You need to reserve a batch of ids (50 of them, for example) in advance before inserting your records from application B. This guarantees that application A will not use any of those ids should it request another batch and it guarantees that application B will not be using any of the currently reserved ids from the instance running application A. It's also important there be some locking approach so that app B's reservation is not accidentally shared.

Comment: Rather than reach directly into the database to manually insert orders, it is a much better pattern to build an API endpoint on the Broadleaf side that translates the order from your other system into a Broadleaf `Order` and then persist that. Then you can avoid this entire sequence_generator problem altogether, along with having better separation between the 2 systems.

Comment: I agree with Phillip. If your design requirements allow, your best bet will be to create an API endpoint that accepts order information and persists the order for you.

Comment: yeah, that could have helped me with not getting into the issue in  first place. But I have restriction of using Java core SE and simple JDBC queries for external application.
I will try the solution where I would have to reserve id's in advance.
Thanks mbvcomebach and phillipuniverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that you need L2 cache invalidation for your external imports if you want your implementation to recognize your new entities at runtime. Otherwise, you would have to wait for the configured TTL on your cache region to expire for your application to see the new records.

However, L2 cache doesn't have any direct correlation to how Hibernate determines primary keys in the case of Broadleaf. Broadleaf utilizes a table generator strategy for grabbing a batch of ids in a performant and cluster-safe way. You probably notice a table entitled SEQUENCE_GENERATOR in your schema. This table contains various id ranges that have been acquired for different domain classes. Whenever Hibernate needs to grab a new batch of ids for insertions, it will interact with this table to register a new range of ids to check out. This should guarantee that no node in the cluster will try to insert an entity with a colliding id.

In your case, you need to guarantee that an external process can perform insertions in a non-colliding manner. To do so, I believe you need to create an API for the external process to call that will perform this same "id checkout" operation on behalf of that calling process. Then, your import code (presumably housed elsewhere) will have a range of ids it can safely use. The code backing the API you create should perform the same operation that Hibernate would normally perform to acquire a batch of ids for entity insertions. You can review org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator for an example of what this looks like and create something similar for your own purposes.

Comment: I just wanted to add, not all the framework classes use a hibernate generator CustomerImpl for instance does not. It uses IdGenerationService

Comment: Good answer. The key is that when you update records in the database, you also need to update the ID range in `SEQUENCE_GENERATOR`. @John is right that `BLC_ID_GENERATION` is for `CustomerImpl`.

Here is an example in MySQL for `BLC_PRODUCT`. This also works if there is not already a `ProductImpl` key. You can run this after inserting a set of products directly `SET @id = (SELECT MAX(product_id) + 1 FROM blc_product); INSERT INTO sequence_generator (ID_NAME, ID_VAL) VALUES ('ProductImpl', @id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_val = @id;`

Comment: @phillipuniverse I am already updating the corresponding entity value in SEQUENCE_GENERATOR table. Still  I am getting old generated primary key from IdOverrideTableGenerator .

Comment: @phillipuniverse mbvcomeback I have updated the question with my initial tries. Please have a look.

Comment: @phillipuniverse Simply updating the sequence generator table after inserting entities would have concurrency problems under load, I imagine. If you choose an id, insert the product and then update the sequence generator table - other processes could beat you to the punch on the sequence generator bit. It's safer to reserve your batch of ids up front and then use those for your inserts. Also, you'll want to perform that reserve in a locking manner (just like Hibernate's TableGenerator) in order to guarantee that no other process accidentally gets your ids.

Comment: True, thanks for the additional comment there. My assumption was with something like a batch import with low (or non-existent) contention then you just want to clean up when you're done.